# Default credentials for Jenkins after installation

Tags: windows, jenkins, windows-10

I have downloaded Jenkins on Windows10. When i try to access jenkins, it is asking for username and password. 
I have read the threads on the same issue. But I do not find any secrets folder or config.xml file under Jenkins folder.

Answer (score 20):

Username is **admin**. Password should be located in:

```
$JENKINS_HOME/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

You can view the password using:

```
cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

or

```
cat $JENKINS_HOME/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the OP was specifically asking about Windows 10 and this answer definitely doesn't look like a Windows 10 answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Jenkins inside of a Docker container, like I am, the following commands might be useful.

```
docker exec -it ${jenkins_container_name} \
    cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword 
# or if it was the last container you ran
docker exec -it $(docker container ls -l --format "{{.Names}}") \
    cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Answer (score 3):

After Installation of `Jenkins 2.Y.Z`, I would suggest you to simply restart your OS.

my `OS` is `Windows 8.1`, and as after I restarted `Jenkins` automatically builds it installation environment, and you can see many directories and files available or appeared which were not available instantly after installation.

Now, Open `Jenkins Dashboard` path in web browser `hostname:portnumber`

for beginners it is like `localhost:8080`

it will ask you the password.

So, open the file `initialAdminPassword` in text editor or viewer located in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets\
```

copy the 32 chars length `password`, and paste it to the `Jenkins` Dashboard.

Later you can install the `plugins` default or in custom choose mode.

Hope this would help many one.

Answer (score 2):

1) open terminal

2) type **docker ps -a**

then you will find the list of containers

3) copy your container id where your Jenkins is running

4) type **docker logs** your_container_id

then you will see

Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

**741bc43e03b54cd9be183d97947c7369**

This may also be found at: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

Answer (score 2):

I found the file in this location on windows server 2019

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\secrets

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue as well. After installing Jenkins, the installation directory just had some config files and the `jre` and `bin` folders. After rebooting Windows 10 I was able to see all the normal folders you would expect in a Jenkins installation:

- jobs
- jre
- logs
- nodes
- plugins
- **secrets** - The "secrets" folder only appeared after rebooting, and in it was `initialAdminPassword` just as promised.

Now going to http://localhost:8080 loads the "Unlock Jenkins" page.

---

Really, though. I should have known to reboot. It is Windows after all...

Answer (score 0):

same issue got resolved after restart, i was able to see folders and jenkin also started responding.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i faced a different issue.
I tried to uninstall and reinstall several times without resetting password.
I also deleted all files in user space.
Then I found there was another folder created as C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.
I had to delete that as well and then it worked fine.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -6):

**open the door**

sudo chmod -R 777 secrets

**peek inside**

vi secrets/initialAdminPassword

**close the door**

sudo chmod -R 700 secrets

Comment: running `sudo` is enough, no need for running `chmod`