# Initial login page for Jenkins 2.141 (Windows)

Tags: jenkins

I recently installed Jenkins 2.141 on Windows. And my initial login page already showed up in my browser. The web address is: http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F
But when I enter user name: admin and password which I get from C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword, the page response with "Invalid username or password".

What's went wrong here?[image: Jenkins Login Page]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840692/default-credentials-for-jenkins-after-installation?rq=1 , did you note down the admin password when you installed Jenkins ?

Comment: The admin password is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword.

Comment: Please try with username 'admin' and password 'admin'

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, go to Jenkins installation directory (*example:* `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets`) and open `initalAdminPassword` in notepad to see the defaults admin password for Jenkins.